# Un-enlisting a BizTalk MSMQ send port in batch file

Tags: msmq, biztalk, port, send

I've got a solution which I setup / cleanup using batch files ...
- there are a pair of MSMQ ports, send and receive, with another application on the end of the queues

I'm finding I can't properly stop the orchestration in the batch file ... the error is the send port is unenlisted
 - I'm using the StopOrch.vbs script from the SDK samples

But I can go into BizTalk Admin Console and manually stop the orchestration with Full Terminate Ok

The setup / cleanup works Ok if I don't actually push any messages down the MSMQ queues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also take a look at the Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM.dll. It is contains business level objects that are pretty nice to interact with in .NET code. You can find the dll in the installation directory, mine is at: *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2009\Developer Tools*

Here is the MSDN documentation on it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.biztalk.explorerom(BTS.20).aspx

And a good high level walk through of its use:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20100324233854/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/claeyskurt/archive/2008/10/13/125815.aspx)

Comment: Thanks ... once we upgrade to BTS 2009  :-(

Comment: SteveC, sorry for the confusion, this exists in BizTalk 2006 R2 as well. That is where I first used it. The path is basically the same: C:\Program Files\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2006\Developer Tools

As long as you use the dll from the BizTalk 2006 installation everything else is basically the same. I did not notice any change in interface when we upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

Steve,

I would look at using a powershell script to handle terminating all the suspended messages and also shutdown the the orchestration the proper way.  I believe there's a set of these scripts on codeplex if you search.  Also look at the SDC MSBuilt components on complex for doing that as well.

-Bryan